# Recording date of an input value in a different sheet(Same Workbook), where input cell is on a different sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to record Timestamp/Date of values entered in a specific column of one Sheet of the same workbook(Ex : Sheet 2) in a specific column of another sheet of the same workbook(Ex : Sheet 1). 
Both these columns have headers where the sheet recording the Input Data has it's header in Row 3. Have tried searching for multiple solutions but none work, using the following code currently.

**Also:

1. I do not have Scripting knowledge/JavaScript knowledge
2. I am simultaneously running two codes(Time Based Trigger & the time stamp is to run onEdit)**

Will be thankful for some help here :)

```
function TimeStamp(event)
{ 
var timezone = "GMT+5.5";
var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy"; // Timestamp Format. 
var updateColName = "Folder ID for Link TS";
var timeStampColName = "Actual date of Link Shared";
var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Probe Sheet'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.


var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to use IMPORTRANGE and "="operator, as the code restricts itself to one sheet, to import the data from the data entry sheet and use OnEdit/OnChange triggers, but they don't seem to work, turns out I need to make a manual edit to make the code effective to record the date  :(

Comment: You say "using the following code currently.".  Does the code do what you want?  If not, what is missing, or what errors do you get?  Are you trying to add data AND a timestamp to Sheet1 when Sheet2 is edited/updated?  Or just a timestamp?  Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Comment: What's the issue you're having? Check if the cell that was modified should be timestamped, and if so, use the Spreadsheet Service to get the sheet you timestamp on, determine the row and column you need to write to, and then write the desired value. As for the format of the timestamp, I highly recommend you **always** include a full timestamp - including timezone - to avoid issues with date comparisons.

Comment: @RonKloberdanz No the code does not serve the purpose. This is bound to only the sheet where I want the Timestamp, wherein when I add data to a specified column in Sheet 1, it returns the timestamp in the same sheet. I am trying to add ONLY timestamp (in sheet 1) against the data recorded in Sheet 2. The spreadsheet has a lot of associated drives and links tagged to it, i wish I could share it but,  it belongs to my employer

Comment: @tehhowch I would be using the timestamp/date stamp in a DATEDIF formula so a full timestamp may hamper the cause. Timezone specification has worked for me so far, when the reference sheet and the output sheet were the same. However, the issue is that :  
1. The above code is restricted to only one sheet.  
2. The data being entered on a seperate sheet on the same workbook(Sheet2) needs to be timestamped on Sheet 1  
3. The data entry column is being searched basis column name, which in the updated code will be in Row 3 and not Row 1.

Comment: A great place to start is by looking up in the Apps Script reference what each of the various Apps Script methods are doing. That includes what values and types of values they take as inputs, and what values / types of values they yield as outputs. If you don't understand your script as written, such that you could explain every line of it to your boss, then you need to rectify that knowledge gap. Once you have a handle on these methods you should be able to make an attempt at modifying the code you've posted, and we can help you fix issues in your modification.

Comment: @tehhowch Agreed ! However, as I mentioned earlier, I am too new into coding to the extent that a simple script like the above took me almost an embarrassing amount of time to decipher. My boss, however understands none of this and I am doing this out of curiosity and willingness to streamline processes, but professional deadlines in this case need to matter more. I would love to figure this out on my own, but I seem to have hit base. Would appreciate some help in modifications to run and compute :)